# divide entire dataframe by 100

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like this;

```
    col1 col2 col3
row1 75  14   45
row2 45  
row3 12       36
```

As you can see, the df contains empty cells.

doing this fails:

```
 dataframe = dataframe/100
```

it returns as typeerror

I want to keep the empty cells but I want to divide the valid values

Comment: `df.div(100)` ? if the blanks are strings, replace them using `df.replace(' ',np.nan)`

Comment: perfect! thanks a lot.